# Dependent pattern matching in coq

Tags: coq

The following code (which is of course not a complete proof) tries to do pattern matching on a dependent product:

```
Record fail : Set :=
  mkFail {
      i : nat ;
      f : forall x, x < i -> nat
    }.

Definition failomat : forall (m : nat) (f : forall x, x < m -> nat), nat.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply 0.
Qed.

Function fail_hard_omat fl : nat := failomat (i fl) (f fl).

Definition failhard fl : fail_hard_omat fl = 0.
refine ((fun fl =>
          match fl with
            | mkFail 0 _ => _
            | mkFail (S n) _ => _
          end) fl).
```

The error I get when trying to execute this is

```
Toplevel input, characters 0-125:
Error: Illegal application (Type Error): 
The term "mkFail" of type
 "forall i : nat, (forall x : nat, x < i -> nat) -> fail"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "i" : "nat"
 "f0" : "forall x : nat, x < i0 -> nat"
The 2nd term has type "forall x : nat, x < i0 -> nat"
which should be coercible to "forall x : nat, x < i -> nat".
```

It seems that the substitution somehow does not reach the inner type parameters.

Comment: Indeed the ``match foo with bar`` construction is not easy to use with dependent type. You will have to explain Coq how the substitution goes with the more complex ``match foo as bar return bli with blo`` construction. I'm not sure how to do it correctly right now, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with the `Program` command I managed to build a refine that might suites you, but I don't understand everything I did. The main idea is to help Coq with the substitution by introducing intermediate equalities that will serve as brige within the substitution

```
    refine ((fun fl =>

    match fl as fl0 return (fl0 = fl -> fail_hard_omat fl0 = 0) with
      | mkFail n bar =>
        match n as n0 return (forall foo: (forall x:nat, x < n0 -> nat), 
           mkFail n0 foo = fl -> fail_hard_omat (mkFail n0 foo) = 0) with 
       | O => _
       | S p => _
       end bar
    end (eq_refl fl) ) fl).
```

Anyway, I don't know what your purpose here is, but I advise never write dependent match "by hand" and rely on Coq's tactics. In your case, if you define your `Definition failomat` with `Defined.` instead of `Qed`, you will be able to unfold it and you won't need dependent matching.

Hope it helps,
V.

Note: both occurences of `bar` can be replaced by an underscore.

Comment: I still think that Coq should do this substitution automatically.

Comment: and I know a lot of person that feel the same :) Feel free to discuss the topic on the Coq-club mailing list. Coq's dev team is quite small and they don't have time for all the good idea, but they have the ideas !

Answer (score 2):

Another, slightly less involved, alternative is to use `nat` and `fail`'s induction combinators.

```
Print nat_rect.
Print fail_rect.

Definition failhard : forall fl, fail_hard_omat fl = 0.
Proof.
refine (fail_rect _ _). (* Performs induction (projection) on fl. *)
refine (nat_rect _ _ _). (* Performs induction on fl's first component. *)
Show Proof.
```

Comment: I thought pattern matching and induction would formally be the same thing. What is the actual difference?

Comment: I don't know why, but as you can see type inference becomes easier. Also, plain pattern matching doesn't allow recursion. You have to use a `fix` or the `Fixpoint` command to get recursion (or more advanced commands like `Function` and `Program`). A `fix` allows without proof certain kinds of recursion that would otherwise need proof when using induction combinators. The `Function` and `Program`  commands make it more convenient to prove termination.