# Implementing safe element retrieval by index from list in Coq

Tags: coq, agda

I'm trying to demonstrate the difference in code generation between Coq Extraction mechanism and MAlonzo compiler in Agda. I came up with this simple example in Agda:

```
data Nat : Set where
  zero : Nat
  succ : Nat → Nat

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  nil : List A
  cons : A → List A → List A

length : ∀ {A} → List A → Nat
length nil = zero
length (cons _ xs) = succ (length xs)

data Fin : Nat → Set where
  finzero : ∀ {n} → Fin (succ n)
  finsucc : ∀ {n} → Fin n → Fin (succ n)

elemAt : ∀ {A} (xs : List A) → Fin (length xs) → A
elemAt nil ()
elemAt (cons x _) finzero = x
elemAt (cons _ xs) (finsucc n) = elemAt xs n
```

Direct translation to Coq (with [absurd pattern emulation](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4242358)) yields:

```
Inductive Nat : Set :=
| zero : Nat
| succ : Nat -> Nat.

Inductive List (A : Type) : Type :=
| nil : List A
| cons : A -> List A -> List A.

Fixpoint length (A : Type) (xs : List A) {struct xs} : Nat :=
   match xs with
   | nil => zero
   | cons _ xs' => succ (length _ xs')
   end.

Inductive Fin : Nat -> Set :=
| finzero : forall n : Nat, Fin (succ n)
| finsucc : forall n : Nat, Fin n -> Fin (succ n).

Lemma finofzero : forall f : Fin zero, False.
Proof. intros a; inversion a. Qed.

Fixpoint elemAt (A : Type) (xs : List A) (n : Fin (length _ xs)) : A :=
   match xs, n with
   | nil, _ => match finofzero n with end
   | cons x _, finzero _ => x
   | cons _ xs', finsucc m n' => elemAt _ xs' n' (* fails *)
   end.
```

But the last case in elemAt fails with:

```
File "./Main.v", line 26, characters 46-48:
Error:
In environment
elemAt : forall (A : Type) (xs : List A), Fin (length A xs) -> A
A : Type
xs : List A
n : Fin (length A xs)
a : A
xs' : List A
n0 : Fin (length A (cons A a xs'))
m : Nat
n' : Fin m
The term "n'" has type "Fin m" while it is expected to have type
 "Fin (length A xs')".
```

It seems that Coq does not infer `succ m = length A (cons A a xs')`. What should I
tell Coq so it would use this information? Or am I doing something completely senseless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing pattern matching is the equivalent of using the `destruct` tactic.
You won't be able to prove `finofzero` directly using `destruct`.

The `inversion` tactic automatically generates some equations before doing what `destruct` does.
Then it tries to do what `discriminate` does. The result is really messy.

```
Print finofzero.
```

- To prove something like `fin zero -> P` you should change it to `fin n -> n = zero -> P` first.
- To prove something like `list nat -> P` (more usually `forall l : list nat, P l`) you don't need to change it to `list A -> A = nat -> P`, because `list`'s only argument is a parameter in its definition.
- To prove something like `S n <= 0 -> False` you should change it to `S n1 <= n2 -> n2 = 0 -> False` first, because the first argument of `<=` is a parameter while the second one isn't.
- In a goal `f x = f y -> P (f y)`, to rewrite with the hypothesis you first need to change the goal to `f x = z -> f y = z -> P z`, and only then will you be able to rewrite with the hypothesis using induction, because the first argument of `=` (actually the second) is a parameter in the definition of `=`.

Try defining `<=` without parameters to see how the induction principle changes.
In general, before using induction on a predicate you should make sure it's arguments are variables. Otherwise information might be lost.

```
Conjecture zero_succ : forall n1, zero = succ n1 -> False.
Conjecture succ_succ : forall n1 n2, succ n1 = succ n2 -> n1 = n2.

Lemma finofzero : forall n1, Fin n1 -> n1 = zero -> False.
Proof.
intros n1 f1.
destruct f1. 
intros e1.
eapply zero_succ.
eapply eq_sym.
eapply e1.
admit.
Qed.

(* Use the Show Proof command to see how the tactics manipulate the proof term. *)
Definition elemAt' : forall (A : Type) (xs : List A) (n : Nat), Fin n -> n = length A xs -> A.
Proof.
fix elemAt 2.
intros A xs.
destruct xs as [| x xs'].
intros n f e.
destruct (finofzero f e).
destruct 1.
intros e.
eapply x.
intros e.
eapply elemAt.
eapply H.
eapply succ_succ.
eapply e.
Defined.

Print elemAt'.

Definition elemAt : forall (A : Type) (xs : List A), Fin (length A xs) -> A :=
  fun A xs f => elemAt' A xs (length A xs) f eq_refl.
```

[CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) has more about this.

Maybe things would be clearer if at the end of a proof Coq performed eta reduction and beta/zeta reduction (wherever variables occur at most once in scope).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is similar to [Dependent pattern matching in coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228912/dependent-pattern-matching-in-coq) . Coq's `match` does not infer much, so you have to help it by providing the equality by hand.